# How to setup a rewrite rule on Azure CDN to serve index.html that don't match a path pattern?

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, cdn, azure-cdn

I want to use Azure CDN (which is powered by EdgeCast, apparently) to serve static content for my React + GraphQL web app.

The CDN will pull the static files from a Storage account, and Node.js will handle the GraphQL endpoint.

For the client-side routing to work properly, I need to serve `/static/index.html` for all requests that don't match the static content path (`/static/somefile.ext`).

I want to avoid using Node.js to serve the `index.html` in this fashion:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile("index.html");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Verizon Premium SKU, you can access the rules engine by clicking 'Manage' from the azure portal.

I would use a rule like this to rewrite everything except your static link to index.html

[image: rewrite rule screencap]

Comment: It would more helpful to describe each field and its value. This helps people to understand how it works, as well as working for those that are visually impaired and cannot read your screenshot. Plus, you'll get more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the "Modify Client Response Header" feature:

[image]