# Is it possible to rewrite request and return a 404 status code with Azure CDN?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I'm looking at putting some rewriter rules in place with Azure CDN

/ ➡️ /index.html

/location ➡️ /location.html

.. and some other patterns

/{anything-else} ➡️ /404.html

I can see this is possible with this [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800105/how-to-setup-a-rewrite-rule-on-azure-cdn-to-serve-index-html-that-dont-match-a) but I was wondering if It's possible to change the status code returned back to the user.

/{anything-else} ➡️ /404.html

StatusCode: 404

Answer (score 1):

There is not a Rules Engine feature to change the status code to a 404. You will need to make your origin return a 404 when a request goes to 404.html.

Comment: The origin for this is just pointing straight at blob storage so this isn't possible